# I don't know why collision works this way

Tags: mesh

Every time I try to collide object that is edited or object which modifier is applied to, this happens. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/288802/edit) your question and describe your problem in detail so that people who are willing to help you don't have to guess what "this happens" means. Currently, since nobody can tell what you mean for sure this question has really slim chances to be answered in a meaningful way.

Comment: Hi, peter123, welcome.. This question gives no clue of what your problem is to potential respondents , before committing them to a download, and is unsearchable in the archive. Could you please edit the title and the content of your post to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Delete the bake, apply the scale of your cylinder and it will work:

[image]